# Help with database strategy for giving roles to users in specific model instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization, user-roles

I have a ruby app running with declarative authorization and I have made the roles:

admin        ( app admin )
org_admin    ( organization administratr )
org_colab    ( organization colaborator )
org_visitor  ( organization visitor )

a User can has_many Organizations and he can be an admin or a colaborator.

I link them using a Affiliation table

What is the best strategy to solve this many to many roles?

To put a extra attribute on the Affiliation table ?
like : Affiliation(:user_id:integer, :organization_id:integer, :affiliation_type:integer)

and the affiliation type can be 0 for org_admin and 1 for org_colab and 2 for org_visitor?

I imagine there must be a better way to assign roles to a particular organization...

Answer (score 2):

It's the classic "User-Group-Role" model.  It's a ternary relationship.  User-Group is many-to-many; so is Group-Role.  You'll need five tables to capture all of it.

You'll start with a User table.  It'll have a primary key (of course).  Same with Group and Role.

You'll have a UserGroup table sitting in-between the User and Group tables in your E/R diagram.  UserGroup will have two columns: user_id and group_id.  The primary key will be the combination (user_id, group_id).  The user_id column will have a foreign key relationship with the primary key of the User table.  Ditto for the group_id column and the Group table.

There will be a similar arrangement with Group and Role.  Each will have a primary key.  The GroupRole table will sit between the two in your E/R diagram.  Repeat the verbiage above and you'll have it.

I'd create an E/R diagram to show you, but I'm busy doing some other things.  I hope this is sufficient for you.  If not, perhaps I'll add it later.

So Users don't have Roles; Groups do.  You add a User to a Group, and that User gets all the authorizations that the Group has.  That way you can add a particular Role (e.g., admin permissions for the Admin group) one for a particular Group.  Then everyone who is added to that Group will get those permissions.

Comment: That was a little vague for me.

Let see, I have this:

User * ---1 Affiliation 1--- * Group

And I was thinking of putting an extra atribute in the Affiliation table for Role type.

Can you explain how the 5 column model is?

Comment: Not a five column model, a five table model.  You'll have User, Group, and Role tables.  You'll also have UserGroup and GroupRole relationship tables to carry the many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Ok... 
my UserGroup is my Affiliation table ( user_id & group_id )
but I don't get it the GroupRole  ? (group_id & role_id) ?
Why is the Group to be associated with a role and not the user?

Comment: I think i've got what you are saying. with that model, i can have user1, user2, and user3 belonging to a group of admins, so they all are admins.   But what I'm after is something like. user1, user2, and user3 belongs to a organization. and user1 is the admin, user2 is the manager, and user3 is the client. It's not a case of grouping roles togueter, but grouping users to a group and have them have a particular role in that group...

Comment: Okay, so have groups Admin, Manager, Client.  Give each one permissions/roles.  Then assign users to the groups.  That's how I'd do it.  That's what I recall from BEA's model for WebLogic.  If you have another design in mind, go for it.  I think you'll need JOIN tables no matter how you do it.

Comment: But the problem is that then one group_admin will be admin in every group and not just in some specific groups that he got assigned to. Right?

Comment: Groups need to be distinguished somehow.  The "Admin" group was an example.  If you need a portal admin, a database admin, etc., then maybe you need additional groups.

Comment: Hi, I've been helping Victor with this one (as of now). The problem that exists and that might not be solvable with this classic U-G-R system is that the Organizations he mentions isn't necessarily a group in itsself, but more of a user. The idea is that users can be part of one or more organizations, assuming one or more roles in those organizations; but users can have roles related to the system, also. the UGR relation will wokr well system-wise, but matbe we need to create a few parallel tables or extra connections to get the organization in to the picture.

Comment: I agree - sounds like you have many-to-many relationships, so you'll need join tables.  You know your situation best - model it appropriately.  Good luck.

Comment: How did you get on with this? I'm in exactly the same position!

Comment: Hey @duffymo stumbled across this question, because I have another issue. Is it not better to just have a column on the Users table called 'Roles' and store the info there in an array ? Why or why not? Or if you don't mind checking out my question I would appreciate it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623599/is-it-better-to-have-roles-as-a-column-on-my-users-table-or-do-it-through-join-t

Answer (score 1):

i actually implement something similar to my project. To clarify if i understand you correct - your user might have a role in the whole application-context, as well as a specific role in the organizational-context which may not depend on each other.

A pragmatic solution might be to implement two different rolesets. Let's think of the following construct: You have a user-model (having application-wide informations), a organization-model (which defines an organization and might possibly be owned by a user) and a collaborative-model which defines a relationship between a user and a organization.

In this case it would be the best to store roles in the user-model (which do the application-wide stuff) and to store organization-specific roles in the collaborative-model.

I used a string based roles-store in the models in combination with ryan bates cancan-gem - its easy & fast to use and puts roles-logic in a defined place.

This might not work for thousands of different roles and groups and stuff, in that case you should implement the role-storage in an extra model (with a polymorphic relation to users and collaboratives).

Best wishes - Florian

edit: To make that implementation searchable by ActiveRecord you might want to use the 'serialize'-feature for the :roles-field, as described in ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: Thanks for your help Florian.
I'm using a system that is very similar to yours, but instead of using cancan i've wrote a Module to manage all the logic issues and evaluate the authorizations. It's far from perfect and I will try to learn other methods in the future, but it's working ok for now.