# Is it better to have roles as a column on my users table, or do it through join tables (Roles & Assignments)? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization

You can see my models here:

https://gist.github.com/768947

Just to explain what is happening, I have a few models. At the core of my app, there are: projects, stages, uploads, comments, users. Then there are roles & assignments to manage user authorization.

I am doing this with the plugin declarative_authorization & devise for login.

So the first question is, is it better to just add a column of 'Roles' to my user model/table and store the roles for each user there? If I have a user that has multiple roles, then I can just store all the roles as an array and cycle through them as needed.

Or is it better to do it like I have it setup now, where I use two separate tables and a bunch of joins to setup the assignments? I only have 4 roles: designer, client, admin, superuser.

Better in the sense that it is 'less expensive' from a computing resources standpoint to do each query with the column, than with the joins or is the difference not that significant?

I guess, the root of my question is...right now if I want to get a project assigned to the current_user I simply do `current_user.projects.each do |project|` and cycle through them that way. This is after I have done: `@projects = current_user.projects` in the projects controller. The same applies for all my other models - except Users & Roles.

However, if I wanted to find a user with role "client", it becomes convoluted very quickly. Or am I overcomplicating it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to have user and role tables that are separate.  It's a many-to-many relationship, because a user can have many roles and many users can have the same role.  You'll need a JOIN table (e.g. user_role) to do that.  I'd recommend three tables.  Of course you'll have primary keys for both user and role; the user_role table will have two columns, one for each primary key, and foreign key relationships to their respective tables.

So now if you want all users with the role "client", it's an easy JOIN between user and user_role.  If you want a particular user's roles, you'll need to JOIN the three tables.

I would not recommend an array of roles in user.  It goes against first normal form.

Comment: Hrmm.....thanks for this response duffymo...but what about scalability issues? Won't having to do more queries (in terms of more joins, instead of a simple row look up) be more detrimental to performance in the long run? When I have 3 tables instead of one with additional columns, what effect does that have on normalization?

Comment: It's far better for normalization.  And databases with far more complex schemas scale very well.  It's still just one query - it happens to JOIN three tables.  No, it's not detrimental to performance until you have a measure you're shooting for, data that says you aren't meeting it, and measurements that tell you the three table JOIN is the culprit.  If that every happens, you'll be able to denormalize as needed.  You're guilty of premature optimization - squared.

Comment: That's what I was concerned about...the premature optimization problem. The thing is, I have it setup like that now (Users, Roles & Assignments) as you can see from the gist posting. However, I was getting advice about accessing the roles and the advice I was given was just that - add a column to the users table. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Also duffymo do you mind just taking a look at this question for me please? This is why I asked this question, so I am trying to get to the root of my problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631218/how-do-i-access-a-user-with-a-specific-role-in-rails-3

Comment: You don't seem to care much for my answers to this question.  It hardly seems worth the time to advise you on anything else.  I'll see if I can give it a look tomorrow.

Comment: Hrmm....that certainly was not what I intended. That's why I voted up the answer + marked it the correct answer. Why else would I do that + ask a bunch of questions to you on 2 or 3 different threads? Me going back and forth with you, was just making sure I put what I was told through the ringer. I had the general inclination that the way you said it was better for right now. But because I am a n00b, I couldn't explain it properly. I just wanted to make sure I was not misunderstanding. I definitely did NOT mean to give you that impression. I apologize if I did. Srsly.

Comment: It's quite opposite to your feeling - more that I am impressed/pleased with your answers, which is why I keep asking you more questions :)